# GetPeerName() returning constant IP address

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, winsock, winsock2

Anytime I call GetPeerName() on a socket in use, I get a constant IP address.

```
SOCKADDR_IN clientAddr;
IN_ADDR clientIn;
int nClientAddrLen;

getpeername(fd, (LPSOCKADDR)&clientAddr, &nClientAddrLen);
memcpy(&clientIn, &clientAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, 4);
printf("client IP address is %s, port is %d", inet_ntoa(clientIn),ntohs(clientAddr.sin_port));
```

Where fd is my already connected socket. I get the same host and port number every time. I am assuming I might be overlooking some small error, but I simply cannot find it. Can anyone offer any assistance?

Comment: How is the socket created? Are you sure you are not connecting through a proxy (in which case you will receive the IP/port of the proxy)?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with getting the same IP and port every time. What do you get, and what do you expect ? And is your socket a connected TCP socket ? You should also make sure getpeername() actually succeeds.

Comment: You know it might be connecting through a proxy... We have to write this for a class and the class itself is on it's own private network so it might work there. 
I constantly get 204.204.204.204 and a port number in the 50,000's. It is a TCP connection. The only way it gets to this function is if the connection succeeds. 

I should add the if not a socket error line to check?

Comment: could be a proxy, a router, whatever your next step on this network is.

Comment: @nos You were right. The problem came from getpeername not actually succeeding. I overlooked a minor detail in the msdn article. The nClientAddrLen needed to be initialized to the side of clientAddr or else it would always return null. 204.204.204.204, the 204 is 0xCC, or the error code for NULL. for future reference to anyone who views this, I changed 

        int nClientAddrLen;
to 
 int nClientAddrLen = sizeof(clientAddr); and it ran just fine

Comment: `0xCC` is not an error code for NULL. It is a debugging tool that some compilers use to initialize memory so you can detect errors when accessing invalid memory. That has nothing to with this issue. Your variable was simply initialized by the compiler, and then `getpeername()` failed and did not overwrite the memory. You still have to do proper error checking. `getpeername()` returns `SOCKET_ERROR` on failure, and then `WSAGetLastError()` tells you why it failed.